# Drupal 9 current IP address doesn't change without clear cache

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-9, drupal-exposed-filter

I have created a view with exposed dropdown where the default exposed value will be changed based on current country. I have got an api which will get the current country based on ip address & it's working absolutely perfect.

I am using a VPN to change the current ip address, & based on ip address the default exposed value is being changed but the problem is that, the same is working only after clear cache.

I tried to disable cache for that partiulat node using the below code, still it's not working.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, $display, $view_mode) {
  if($node->id()==144) {
    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
   \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
  }
```

The full code looks like this:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if(($view->id() === 'myview_id') && ($view->current_display === 'block_1')) {
    $exposed_input = $view->getExposedInput();
    $currentIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ipdat = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $currentIP));

    $currentCountry = $ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;

    if($currentCountry=='India') {
      $defaultCountryCode = 26;
      $exposed_input['field_myfield_target_id'] = $defaultCountryCode;
      $view->setExposedInput($exposed_input);
    }
    elseif($currentCountry=='Russia') {
      $defaultCountryCode = 174;
      $exposed_input['field_myfield_target_id'] = $defaultCountryCode;
      $view->setExposedInput($exposed_input);
    }
    else {
      $defaultCountryCode = 26;
      $exposed_input['field_product_geography_area_target_id'] = $defaultCountryCode;
      $view->setExposedInput($exposed_input);
    }
  }
}
```

How my application will catch the current IP address without clear cache? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Views** also have **caches**. Please check your **view's** cache configs.

If you wanna dive deep and **optimize more**;

You can check https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts and you can use **ip cache context**.

If you wanna dive deep and **optimize more**;

You can create a country cache context **plugin** and **cache per country** instead of ip. Here is the **exact** example: https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Cache/Context/CountryCacheContext.php

Additional **IMPORTANT** Note: Using third-party API in a Cache context plugin is a **really bad idea** and not **sustainable**. I suggest you use https://www.php.net/geoip or at least cache your API results additionally.

Regards,